# Given a list of candidates, can we hit target value in linear time?

Tags: algorithm

I recently was asked this question. I bombed it and I'd love some help with it. The question went like this:

You're given a list of numbers. The numbers are all **positive integers**. So imagine them something like this:

```
[x_0, x_1, ..., x_{n-2}, x_{n-1}]
```

So we have `n` numbers. There's no guarantee that the numbers are different. We also have a target value. Let's call this `X`. `X` is also a positive integer.

The goal is to output a boolean just `True/False` if we can express the target number, `X`, in terms of the candidate in the following form:

```
a * x_0 + b * x_1 + ...
```

The only constraint for the coefficients is that they also have to be positive integers greater than or equal to 0.

You can get the answer in linear time by doing just a bit of math with your candidate numbers. However, I was curious if I could see the algorithm a bit more fleshed out. It doesn't need to be coded up - I can do that - but I still don't exactly have the algorithm. I was thinking maybe something similar in approach to the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or maybe even the [Diophantine Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation.html). Regardless, I couldn't find a clean writeup of the solution anywhere online and was curious if this problem as been explored more.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Thanks again! Really appreciate your help!

Comment: If the coefficients could be simple integers, all you need to do is verify that `gcd(x_0, x_1, ..., x_n)` divides `X`.  The rest of it is tracing Euclid's algorithm backwards to get the GCD, then multiplying by the right number to get to `X`.  But it gets trickier to figure out that `a*21 + b*35` can't be `49` with positive coefficients...

Comment: @btilly But how would this work for something with no common denominators? I agree that your algorithm could work for simple test cases, but consider the target `X=27` and our candidates are `[2, 3]`. There is no gcd between 2 and 3, so we could just have to check the combinations between 2 and 3, thus leading to brute force. Is this the correct line of thinking re your algo? Thanks!

Comment: The GCD between them is `1 = 3 - 2`, so the simple algorithm would come up with `27 * 3 - 27 * 2`.  As you see, coefficients, but not positive.

Comment: @btilly Ah ok I see! Right ok so if we changed the problem to allow for any type of coefficients, then this could be a great potential solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using a sieve could look something like this:

Create an array of boolean with size X+1, with zero set to true and all other values set to false. Then, for every value x<sub>i</sub>

- skip to the next value if x<sub>i</sub> is already set to true (a combination of previous numbers can be used to form x<sub>i</sub> and all its multiples).
- else, iterate over the array (from 0 to X-x<sub>i</sub>)  and for every value x<sub>k</sub> which is true, set x<sub>k</sub>+x<sub>i</sub> to true.
- as soon as value X is set to true, return true.

Sorting the values from small to large first may increase the chance that you can skip some values.

Example:

```
X = 21, x = {4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15}  

 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

x = 4:  
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}

x = 6:  
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}

x = 8: skip

x = 10: skip

x = 11:
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21  
{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
10 + 11 = 21  ->  return true
```

The worst case (no values skipped, result is false) complexity of this is N×X, while in the best case (the first value for x divides X) a solution is found nearly instantly. Calculating an average case complexity is not straightforward, I fear.

Comment: The time complexity of this algorithm is n^2 but I guess the idea of OP was to come up with a linear time algorithm.

Comment: I was just generalizing the running time complexity. n^2 or n*X, it's still treated as quadratic in nature.

Comment: @m69 I see what you're saying! Yeah I think this is it. That's also a good runtime analysis. In hindsight, strictly linear is not possible I think. The question might have been unfair then. But yeah! This is perfect and makes great sense :) thanks for your time.